# Pass data between two php pages while both are opened

Tags: php

I have some PHP files in some project. This project contains two main parts. These are "Admin" and "user". My project folder is much likely:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project
```

Say I have an admin panel page named "admin_panel.php" in such directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\project\admin\admin_panel.php`

as well as I have also a user page named "**user_file.php**" in such directory

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\user\user_file.php
```

Both files are opened in two browsers say in chrome and firefox.

Now I want to pass some notification with yes/no button from "**admin_panel.php**" to "**user_file.php**". Whenever "**user_file.php**" get that content, one can press yes/no and this data is needed to send to "**admin_panel.php**" to take proper action.

How these can be done. Any answer will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, if you don't want to reload the page for update data, you can do mostly two thing: Long-Poll, or Websocket server. Google the rest. http://fdvsolutions.com/blog/websockets-vs-long-polling/

Comment: You could also send this information via ajax-calls, as long as the pages are on the same server (domain), and process the content of the data. Would mean you would have to continously run a js-script on the user-side, however - websockets would probably be a better solution.

Comment: Say, I want to send a string "yes" to another page. Then what code I have to write, if I want to do with ajax.

Comment: Highlighted the important elements in the question, removed extra slashes present in the text

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Sessions" with PHP, which you can update with AJAX

```
            $.ajax({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'somephp.php',
              data: {
                'someinfo': info,
                'ajax': true
              },
              success: function(data) {
                      //if you want to do anything else
              }
            });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["info"] = $_POST["info"];
       //or what ever
?>
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous - yes.

Comment: It will be helpful for me if you write it in more detail such as what I have to do in admin_panel.php and what I have to do in user_file.php. 

Thanks to you in advance.

Comment: I don't know, what you want to do exactly, if there is a database in the background, ajax would be fine, but if you just send messages from user to user it's useless, and you would need to use websockets.. try this maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: I have a database.

Comment: I want to pass some notification with yes/no button from "admin_panel.php" to "user_file.php". Whenever "user_file.php" get that content, one can press yes/no and this data is needed to send to "admin_panel.php" to take proper action.

Comment: Well so i get you dont want to save this in the databse, so besser use websockets, easiest and faest way.. the link shows an javascrpt example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: In above answer, the code gets error.
"info is not defined"